# algorithm for Encr/Decr String Value

Tags: c#, algorithm, encryption

Is there any algorithm for Encrypt and Decrypt String values not exactly in .net ? I don't want to use .net libraries... like RijndaelManaged or something like this.

can u suggest me useful algorithm that implements in C# language?

Comment: please try to re-phrase your question. Algorithm has no relation to a programming language

Comment: **Why** don't you want to use the built-in encryption classes?

Comment: You could write your own Caesar cipher if you like to play with encryption yourself.

Comment: Well, ECIES using one of the safecurve primes is not in C#, and I would think it is pretty useful. But that may not be what you're after - what you're after is hard to tell from the question so -1.

Answer (score 2):

An encryption algorithm is just a mathematical rule for changing a bunch of data into something else in order to hide it. It it not dependent on any specific programming language, just as calculating the area of a rectangle is not dependent on language - it can be done in many different languages, and should give the same result regardless.

You might want to browse some of the [questions tagged with "encryption"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encryption?sort=frequent&pageSize=15) in the Information Security site. That should give you a good idea about how this stuff works and is used for different situations.

To answer your question: You probably want to find some generic algorithm that is supported in several languages. The RSA algorithm may be what you need, and it is supported in C# / .Net by using the [RSACryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: I didnt mean altorithm with any specific programming language, I said that I want an algorithm that implements in C# language. I dont want to use any .net libraries in algorithm.